# How do I use my maven user settings.xml in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I am having own customized maven settings.xml and using same in Eclipse IDE, which is working fine. I want to  configure same settings.xml for intellij IDE. So I used same but it is not working. As per my understanding maven setting will be same for both.

So, can we same settings.xml for both or do I need to configure in different way for intellij.

Comment: No just import your project into IDEA Intellij and it works. The question is what you have customized? And does your build work on plain command line ....

Comment: I have added some repo manager to download some dependencies.

Comment: Repos can only be defined to download dependencies but not a repo for a particular dependencies furthermore in a corporate environment you should always use a repository manager...

Comment: yes thats what i was saying

Answer (score 4):

By default, IntelliJ IDEA uses `settings.xml` in the m2 repo (`~/.m2/settings.xml` on Linux for example). You can override this by using the `Override` checkbox for `User settings file` in the Maven configuration for IntelliJ. See documentation for how to go about that here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/new-projects-from-scratch-maven-settings-page.html

So you should be able to use that to point maven to your custom Maven `settings.xml`. I could do so myself with Intellij IDEA 2021.2.3 Ultimate Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Maven `settings.xml` is not dependent on the IDE.

Comment: in intellij we can override what settings.xml is used, as answered by @swoop81

Comment: @JustAnotherProgrammer Yes, but that was not the question.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @JF Meier the Maven `settings.xml` is independent of IDE. Maybe you should check the maven setting in Intellij and point to the correct installation.

```
File -> Settings -> Search for Maven -> Verify the configured maven directory
```